# How to read a csv file from S3 bucket using AWS lambda and write it as new CSV to another S3 bucket? Python boto3

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Ok so I am a beginner to AWS in general. I am writing a lambda function to trigger based on file upload event in S3, remove some coulmns and write it to a new bucket. Been banging my head for the past two datas and I am getting different error each time. Can someone modify my code/fix it? outputlv will be my target bucket.. Currently I am getting '/outputlv/output.csv' path does not exist in the with open('/outputlv/output.csv', 'w') as output_file line. Thanks.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import csv

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    file_name = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    
    
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_name)
        
        
    with open('/outputlv/output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        wtr = csv.writer(output_file)
        for i in csv_reader:
            wtr.writerow(i[0], i[2], i[3])
            
    target_bucket = 'outputlv'
    final_file = 'outputlv/output.csv'
    
    s3.put_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=final_file)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the content, is it required to work with local files at all ?

```py
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

# Get file content
content = response['Body'].read()

# Pass file content to csv reader
csv_reader = csv.reader(content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't getting the file content in my code and it was the root cause for all the errors.